# Where can I store common cross-site text (e.g. headings, titles etc.)

Tags: admin

I am developing a site that I want to hand over to a client once complete. The core page 'content' is manageable, but there are elements of content (common headings, titles etc.) that are shared across multiple pages & sections within the site, and I would like to give the client a single 'admin page' where they can set all of this information; there are about 25 bits of configurable content - all of them small strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build a theme settings page for all the "global" settings like social media url:s, phone number etc..

It could be something like this:
[image]

Here is a guide how to make a Settings page:

[How to build a theme options page.](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/02/creating-a-custom-wordpress-theme-options-page/)

Or you can make a settings page with the new Customizer that comes with WordPress 3.4 so you can see your updates before you save it:

Look at this video to see what i mean:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD8v6u3noPg&feature=player_embedded

And here is how you can do it:
http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/

Comment: Thanks - does this enable users to edit the settings' values via the admin functionality (i.e. without requiring developers)?

Comment: Yes, but you have to develop the settings panel to work whit your theme. Then, lets say you have created a input field called "Twitter Account" and saved as "twitter" you can then get it by `get_option('twitter'); ` . your users can then change the Twitter account within the admin easy as saving a post.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a perfect use of the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).  Just store the values in transients and you can access them easily anywhere in your theme using:

```
get_transient('transientname');
```